# Can we prove/disprove that Brownian motion is nowhere differentiable in $L^2$?

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I have read the proof that Brownian motion is a.s. nowhere differentiable.

However can we construct a proof that Brownian motion is no where differentiable in $L^2$ for an appropriate definition of $L^2$ differentiability?

If not can we disprove this claim?

Comment: you already have the solution : $\frac{W(t+h)-W(t)}{\sqrt{h}}$ is a continuous R.V. with $0$ mean and variance $1$, so when $h \to 0 : \quad$ $\frac{W(t+h)-W(t)}{h}$ diverges. the only thing you could possibly try would be $\lim_{h \to 0^+}\text{sign}\left(\frac{W(t+h)-W(t)}{h}\right)$

Comment: read a course. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_mean

Comment: @ seek : What meaning do you give to $L^2$ differentiability ? Best regards.

Comment: @TheBridge I was hoping someone might formalize it. As to what I would think (I am not even close to an expert): if $w(h)=\frac{W(t+h)-W(t)}{h}$ then nowhere differentiable in $L^2$ if $E(\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} w(h))^2=\infty.$ Or else $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} E(w(h))^2=\infty.$ Do any of these definitions make sense? Thank you.

Comment: @seek so maybe you should reformulate your question accordingly, giving your initial question as a motivation only ? Best regards